# Convert SimpleJdbcTemplate to DataSource to be able to access a resource from within another resource

Tags: java, spring, rest, sqldatasource, jdbctemplate

i'm using Java Spring to create a REST-Interface

I am trying to access the .get() function of a specific resource A from within the .get() function of another resource B. (to avoid copy-pasting some DB-Query code)

[RESOURCE-A] --access--> [RESOURCE-B] then return combined Result

Is this possible? If so, how?

My idea was to try and fill the DataSource of the resource B with my own jdbcTemplate from A, then call the .get() function... this fails because i can not cast the jdbcTemplate to DataSource ;(

```
// within ResourceA...

ResourceB rB = new ResourceB();
rB.setDataSource( (DataSource) this.jdbcTemplate );
theResultItem.parentList = (List<ResourceB>) rB.get("country", language);
```

Is there a possibility to create a DataSource from a SimpleJDBCTemplate? Or any other way to cross-access resources?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a little coffe-break helps...

I now just inserted an additional method into the second resource, which helps me inject the jdbcTemplate:

```
    //within resource B
    public void setSimpleJdbcTemplate(SimpleJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
     this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
```

and from within resource A i now call

```
    //within resource A
    ResourceB rB = new ResourceB();
    rB.setSimpleJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    theResultItem.parentElements = (List<ResourceB>) pr.get("country", language);
```